# WSO2 API Manager run on HTTP Protocol

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am working on WSO2 API Manager 2.0.0 default zip configuration file and when I run wso2server.bat file the services run on,

**https**://localhost:9443/publisher

**https**://localhost:9443/store

**https**://localhost:9443/carbon

What changes should be done to make them run on HTTP protocol?
**http**://localhost:9443/publisher

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `redirectPort` in `<APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml`

```
<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               port="9763"
               redirectPort="9443"
               bindOnInit="false"
```

Then you should be able to access http via port `9763`.

Comment: Only Store is working on http. Publisher & carbon are re directing to https